# How to regroup a treemap with java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, treemap

I have a `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>` instance and I want to reassign the key value mappings in that way that the lowest key is assigned to the lowest value and the highest key to the highest key.

Here is how I do it without streams:

```
 TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
 map.put(1, 6);
 map.put(2, 9);
 map.put(4, 2);
 map.put(3, 1);
 map.put(8, 10);
 map.put(5, 10);

 ArrayList<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
 Collections.sort(valueList);

 int i = 0;
 for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
      entry.setValue(valueList.get(i++));
 }

 System.out.println(map);
```

output:

```
{1=1, 2=2, 3=6, 4=9, 5=10, 8=10}
```

Any hints how to perform such a task utilizing java-8  Stream API are welcome.

Thx

Comment: Hint: The `supplier` to your `collect` operation should pertain to constructing a `TreeMap`(which is naturally sorted by the nature of these keys without a `Comparator`). Once you try and don't succeed, tag me to retract a close vote.

Comment: `LinkedList<Integer> valueList = new LinkedList<>(map.values());
        Collections.sort(valueList);
        map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> entry.setValue(valueList.pop()));`

Comment: @HadiJ: Post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Nikolas, Thanks for your vote. OP solution has a low cost in comparison with mine.

Comment: I believe the clarity and maintainability of a solution go over the performance.

Comment: @HadiJ the performance of your comment is only slightly slower compared to the OP solution, but much shorter and better readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found out a solution that is fairly easy to read and use:

```
Iterator<Integer> keyIterator = map.keySet().iterator();
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> newMap = map.values().stream()
    .sorted()
    .map(value -> new SimpleEntry<>(keyIterator.next(), value))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (l, r) -> l, TreeMap::new));
```

.. or shorter thanks to [@HadiJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669698/hadi-j):

```
map.values().stream()
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> keyIterator.next(),  Function.identity(), (l, r) -> l, TreeMap::new));
```

... but it has a significant **drawback**:

I cannot guarantee this will work in parallel since it depends on the result of `keyIterator.next()` which is also not checked. Read more at the section [Stateless Behaviors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). I'd rather not use [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) in this way.

---

If I were you, I'd use the advantage of the beauty of iterators:

```
Iterator<Integer> values = valueList.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> keys = map.keySet().iterator();

TreeMap<Integer, Integer> newMap = new TreeMap<>();   // create a new Map
while (values.hasNext() && keys.hasNext()) {          // iterate simultaneously
    newMap.put(keys.next(), values.next());           // put the key-value
}
```

Comment: simplify a bit `map.values().stream()
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->keyIterator.next(), Function.identity(), (l, r) -> l, TreeMap::new));`

Comment: @HadiJ: Yeah, the mapping can happen inside the collector. If you don't mind, I have edited my answer with a reference to you.

Comment: @HadiJ and Nikolas very readable and clear solutions +1. I was trying to do it in a stream without any reference to any other variable beside the map, but so far I've not come up with an idea how to do it.

Comment: @pero_hero, I guess it isn't possible. this is another way: `Map<Integer,Integer> reMap = map.entrySet().stream()
               .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->map.pollFirstEntry().getKey(),
                                          Map.Entry::getValue,(a,b)->a,LinkedHashMap::new)
                        );`

Comment: @HadiJ I managed now to make it run without other references, but it s ugly and slow https://codeshare.io/5wzegj

Comment: @pero_hero, I saw. yeah, so verbose :)

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is not bad. You can shorten it to

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>(map.values());
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> e.setValue(q.remove()));
```

I don't think that this task is a good candidate for the Stream API.

Comment: A good answer, these implementations are underrated, I think. Btw. you can program to an interface: `Queue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>(map.values());`.

Comment: Very succinct with a nice performance +1. You are right with the assumption that this problem is not easily "streamable", but wanted to learn something.

Comment: @Nikolas my first variant was `var q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(map.values());`, then I changed it to match the `java-8` tag. When defining an API, I’d always use the most abstract type, like you suggested. For a local variable used only in the subsequent line, it’s not that important.